# Stubbing a nested function using Sinon.js

Tags: node.js, sinon, sinon-chai

I have a nested object ->

```
let somevar = {
    read : () => {
        return {
            fetchsomething : () => {
                somemodule.methodName(params, cb (err,data) {
                    if(err){
                        //reject promise
                    }
                    else {
                        //resolve promise
                    }
                });
                //return promise obj
            }
        }
    }   
};
```

Now i want to stub 'methodName' and not able to do so. Have tried returning it on the stub, but not sure whats the right thing to do.

Comment: How is `submodule` defined in the example code above? `const submodule = require('submoudle');`?

Comment: import supermodule from {supermodule-sdk}; const somemodule = supermodule.Somemodule();